# Activation Function for Neural Network based Face Detection System

Tags: neural-network, face-detection

I'm trying to implement Face Detection with Neural Network using Rowley's method.
www.informedia.cs.cmu.edu/documents/rowley-ieee.pdf

My problem is that i cant find anything about the activation function used in the proposed NN. Have anyone tried to implement Rowley's method, and what activation function should be used? thanks.

Comment: Use `tanh` or `sigmoid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hyperbolic tangent (TanH) function because 1) paper says that: "The neural network produce real values between 1 and -1" - that rules out sigmoid 2) [earlier Rowley paper](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse577/05sp/papers/rowley.pdf) references [LeCun 1989 work](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/273ASpring09/lecun-89e.pdf) while discussing network architecture, and that paper explicitly mention hyperbolic tangent.